# How can I migrate saved state for an Azure durable entity from function based to class based?

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions, .net-8.0

## Problem

I discovered to my horror that class based durable entities in Azure Function persist state differently than function based entities.

Class based entities serialise state to json and put it directly in the `state` property:

```
{"state":"{\"Value\":1}"}
```

Function based entities first assign the state to a property with the name as the state type, then serialise:

```
{"state":"{\"MyState\":{\"Value\":1}}"}
```

## Scenario

A function based durable entity is rewritten as a class based entity to take advantage of all dependency injection goodness in .NET.

How can I read or migrate the already persisted, function based state so that the class based function can operate properly?

## Demonstration

One can demonstrate the results by doing:

```cs
public class AzureFunctionTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
{
    [Fact]
    public void Serialize_state()
    {
        output.WriteLine(SerializeFunction(new MyState(1)));
        // {"state":"{\"MyState\":{\"Value\":1}}"}
        
        output.WriteLine(SerializeClass(new MyState(1)));
        // {"state":"{\"Value\":1}"}
    }

    static string SerializeFunction<T>(T state)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, object?>
        {
            [typeof(T).Name] = state
        };
        
        var serializedProperties = JsonSerializer.Serialize(properties);
        var entityState = new EntityState(serializedProperties);
        return Serialize(entityState);

    }

    static string SerializeClass<T>(T state)
    {
        var serializedProperties = JsonSerializer.Serialize(state);
        var entityState = new EntityState(serializedProperties);
        return Serialize(entityState);
    }

    static string Serialize(EntityState functionState)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web) { Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(functionState, options);
    }

    record EntityState(string State);

    record MyState(int Value);
}
```

Comment: The two serialization results in the top of the question are identical. I assume this is a copy&paste error. In your code, the difference is obvious. You may want to fix that.